# Joomla template show image thumbnail on frontpage

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-template

Using joomla 1.5 how do you add thumbnail images to the list of articles on the frontpage.

What I am after is something similar to this http://templates.joomlart.com/ja_quartz/ (scroll down to the list under welcome to the frontpage)  As you can see this shows the date, then a thumbnail image and then a snippet of the article with a read more link. If this is an extension does anyone know which one it is?  I don't want to buy the template as I am just after that specific piece of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% certain, but it looks like they simply overloaded the `arlicle blog` layout, custom layout in `template/html/com_content/` directory.

Look at there 2 components, you can achieve pretty much the same thing:

1. [K2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction/8061)
2. [ZOO, from Yootheme](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction/12479)

Both are great. Personally I would go with Zoo, Yotheme does a fantastic job at all their products. Code is clean and easy to modify. Have not worked much with K2, have not heard any bad things about it.

Answer (score 0):

The sample you linked specifically does it with the standard Joomla content component. They are using a template override that styles the article intro text to look like that.

As Alex mentioned, K2 and ZOO both have that style capability built in. I am a K2 user and that type listing is one of the defaults. K2 allows the user to associate an image with a content item that can then be displayed in several sizes and locations. I have not used ZOO much, but Yootheme does have pretty nice code. Either way would probably work well.