# How to add thumbnail to an article in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

Is there any extension that helps me to add a thumbnail manually to an article?
Not those exts which do it on the fly using the first image in the article.
I want to add it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857479/joomla-template-show-image-thumbnail-on-frontpage/3858109#3858109).

Look at there 2 components, you can achieve pretty much the same thing:

1. [K2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction/8061)
2. [ZOO, from Yootheme](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction/12479)

I was a big fan of ZOO, but lately I became fan of K2.