# Joomla extension for content

Tags: joomla

I need help to find an extension or a way in joomla to display an introduction of an article with an image, but when I click in the article it shows the full article without the image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Display the article where? What have you tried so far yourself? The people on SO won't do your work for you and we all expect you to have atleast made the effort to try something yourself first

Comment: Apparently they will as there has been an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is pretty easy to do with native articles. Simply enable "show more" setting and keep image there, and use read more tag.

Until now best 3rd party components still are: [Yootheme Zoo](http://www.yootheme.com/zoo) and [K2](http://getk2.org/)

See this thread: [Joomla template show image thumbnail on frontpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857479/joomla-template-show-image-thumbnail-on-frontpage/3858109#3858109)